# Time complexity of checking if a binary tree is balanced

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I am practicing some interview questions and I trying to figure out the time complexity of my solution to determine if a given binary tree is balanced.

I believe that solution 2 has a time complexity of `O(n)` while solution 1 has a time complexity of `O(n^2)`. This is due to the fact that in solution 1, you recurse down to the bottom of the tree to check if the tree is balanced and also check for differences in subtree height. The extra complexity comes as we go higher back up the tree towards the root, the get_height still recurses down the tree to compute the height. Therefore, traveling down the tree once more --> `O(n^2)`.

The fact that solution 2 compares the height first, means that as we move back up the tree, we dont have to go back down to check the subtree height.

helper:

```
def get_height(root):
    if root is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return max(get_height(root.left), get_height(root.right)) + 1
```

Solution 1:

```
def is_balanced(root):
    if root is None:
        return True
    else:
        return is_balanced(root.right) and is_balanced(root.left) and (abs(get_height(root.left) - get_height(root.right)) < 2)
```

Solution 2:

```
def is_balanced2(root):
    if root is None:
        return True
    else:
        return (abs(get_height(root.left) - get_height(root.right)) < 2) and is_balanced(root.right) and is_balanced(root.left)
```

code to check time differences:

```
s = time.time()
print("result: {}".format(is_balanced(a)))
print("time: {}".format(time.time() - s))

s = time.time()
print("result: {}".format(is_balanced2(a)))
print("time: {}".format(time.time() - s))
```

results for an unbalanced tree:

```
result: False
time: 2.90870666504e-05    # solution 1
result: False
time: 1.50203704834e-05    # solution 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe that solution 2 has a time complexity of O(n) while solution 1 has a time complexity of O(n^2).

I believe otherwise, as explained below.

> ...in solution 1, you recurse down to the bottom of the tree to check if the tree is balanced and also check for differences in subtree height. The extra complexity comes as we go higher back up the tree towards the root, the get_height still recurses down the tree to compute the height. Therefore, traveling down the tree once more --> O(n^2).

It's not so simple.  Say you call `is_balanced()` on the root: as it recursively visits each node in the tree, it calls `get_height` which recursively visits the sub-tree there-under.  For the root, `get_height` visits pretty much the entire tree: N-1 operations, so O(N).  For each of the root's 2 children, `get_height` visits their (roughly) half the tree: again O(N).  This continues until `get_height` is operating on the ~N `None` nodes under the N/2 leaf nodes: still O(N).  In total, there are ~log2N levels in the tree, you're doing O(N) processing on each, so overall complexity is O(NlogN).

> The fact that solution 2 compares the height first, means that as we move back up the tree, we dont have to go back down to check the subtree height.

Nope.  What you've changed in solution two is the order of the `is_balanced` vs. `get_height` checks are performed.  With any tree for which both tests eventually pass, the total amount of processing - and therefore the big-O efficiency - is unchanged.

Separately, your logic does not check for a balanced binary tree: you might want to re-read the definition.

Comment: I'm not sure how my solutions does not check if a binary tree is balanced. Could you please provide some examples? Thank you

Comment: @Liondancer: consider the example tree on [Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) introduced with *"A balanced binary tree has the minimum possible maximum height (a.k.a. depth) for the leaf nodes"*: for the balanced tree at left, the left branch ABCD has height 3 (using their root=0 counting), while the right branch E has 1... that wouldn't pass your `abs(get_height(root.left) - get_height(root.right)) < 2)` condition.  As Wikipedia says, a height difference of <2 is common in balanced binary trees - even guaranteed by some insertion algos - but not part of the definition.

Comment: @TonyDelroy That part of the Wikipedia article has by now been fixed. I suggest you fix your answer as well, i.e., delete your last paragraph and use the definition of balance used by the question in your analysis. And for the complexity statement, you'd need to discuss not just balanced but also unbalanced trees.

Comment: Hi @KellyBundy - thanks for letting me know there's an issue.  Unfortunately I don't have time to revisit this for now, so I'll delete my answer.  Cheers