# Space complexity of checking if binary tree is balanced

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, space-complexity

I'm trying to understand the time and space complexity of this code for determining whether a Binary tree is balanced:

```
def height(t):
    if t is None:
        return 0

    return max(height(t.left), height(t.right)) + 1

def is_balanced_binary_tree(tree: BinaryTreeNode) -\> bool:
    if tree is None:
        return True

    if abs(height(tree.left) - height(tree.right)) > 1:
        return False
    
    return is_balanced_binary_tree(tree.left) and is_balanced_binary_tree(tree.right)
```

Time complexity is `O(NlogN)`; but I'm not sure how to think about space complexity in the context of 4 function calls made from `is_balanced_binary_tree` and 2 in `height`. What we do know is that from the root node, we can expect to call `4 * H` functions, where `H` is the height of the tree. Does this generalize over touching `N` nodes, to give a space complexity of `4*H*N`?

Comment: Just curious: how did you determine the time complexity?

Comment: For a recursive function, the (stack) space used is proportional to the maximum recursion depth. You can experimentally find the maximum recursion depth by adding a `depth` parameter to the two functions. Print the depth at the top of each function, and pass `depth+1` in the recursive calls. I expect that you'll find that the maximum depth is `H` (±1)

Comment: @KellyBundy the question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258139/time-complexity-of-checking-if-a-binary-tree-is-balanced?rq=2)

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, as it seemed odd that you could do the harder thing but not the trivial thing.

Comment: @KellyBundy my confusion is with regard to how the stack space should be analyzed; i think i am over thinking it. It is easy to see that the maximum recursion depth is `H`; but I don't know how to "sum" over the fact that, for a node, we call `height` twice and `is_balanced_binary_tree` another two times. If we made a trivial recursive function, with a single call in is_balanced_binary_tree to `height`, I can see why the answer for stack space is `H`. I don't know how to extend this analysis though to all these function calls happening in the same parent frame. If that makes sense ..

Comment: Yeah you're overthinking it :-). If you bike to school and back 10 times, how many bikes do you need?